# Why read.csv fails in R console in Ubuntu terminal but works in RStudio after R 3.6.3 upgrade to R 4.0.2?

Tags: r, rstudio, read.csv, r-4.0

I am trying to download some data and it works perfectly in RStudio and fails in R console in terminal in Ubuntu 18.04 after upgrade from R 3.6.3 to 4.0.2. Before upgrade this worked in R console in terminal also without any issues.

Why would that be? How to fix this?

Below please find R code output and sessionInfo().

**Works in RStudio**

```
> read.csv("https://old.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=1&render=download", header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE, na="n/a")
    Symbol                                                Name LastSale MarketCap IPOyear
1      TXG                                  10x Genomics, Inc.  87.4400     $8.6B    2019
2       YI                                           111, Inc.   6.4800  $533.69M    2018
3      PIH              1347 Property Insurance Holdings, Inc.   4.5350   $27.52M    2014
 sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.2 tools_4.0.2
```

**Fails in R console in terminal**

```
    > read.csv("https://old.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=1&render=download", header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE, na="n/a")
Error in file(file, "rt") : 
  cannot open the connection to 'https://old.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=1&render=download'
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  URL 'https://old.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=1&render=download': status was 'Failure when receiving data from the peer'
> traceback()
3: file(file, "rt")
2: read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, 
       dec = dec, fill = fill, comment.char = comment.char, ...)
1: read.csv("https://old.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=1&render=download", 
       header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, na = "n/a")
>  sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.2
>
```

Comment: Possibly you do not have your  terminal session, or your "raw" R.exe  running at the same privilege level (user vs. admin, for example) as your RStudio installation.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thanks. Tried and run "sudo R" instead of just "R" in terminal and result is the same error. So I maybe lack of permissions is the cause here.